# Windows 10 image from Clonezilla comes up in GMT-1

Tags: windows-10, disk-image, clonezilla, time-zone

Mixed Win8.1 / Win10 shop, Linux infrastructure. Jenkins runs machines; OS, apps, drivers, Clonezilla supplies OS images. Images installed by PXE boot/Jenkins coercing it. With release of Win10, co-worker created Win-10 release image. It has the right time zone (California, UTC-8). But sometimes/always, it's the wrong time of day. 7 hours late. Not UTC-8, not UCT/GMT, but UTC-1.  As if on a fishing boat, or an island...

If I right-click on the clock, lower right corner, left-click "Adjust Date and Time", time zone is correct, "Set time automatically" set "On". When I click it off and then back on, the time resets to correct local time, UTC-8.

I don't see other questions about this, so we did it to ourselves, but it isn't clear how. Has anyone else had trouble with the time of day, but not the time zone, coming up wrong in restored Win10 images from Clonezilla?

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem. Clonezilla seems to ignore the `timezone` boot parameter, gets the time from NTP, and seems to save the time as UTC to the hardware clock. But Windows expects the hardware clock to be in localtime, not UTC. Still looking for a solution...

Comment: It might be fixed in the latest Clonezilla. See this thread: https://sourceforge.net/p/clonezilla/discussion/Clonezilla_live/thread/b2667447/